# Two different Paypal Forms based on User's Status

Tags: php, sql, forms, paypal, registration

I created a website that has a registration form for a fundraiser event. It has simple fields such as "First Name, Last Name, Email, etc" After they click on **"submit"** on the first page, they are taken to another page where they can pay via Paypal.

I already know how to insert the Paypal feature where it says "Buy now". However, for my case, I want to have 2 different Paypal forms:

1. If a user has already registered for another particular conference, they pay $10  (I have the list of registered attendees in a database table already via phpmyadmin)
2. If a user has not registered for the general conference, they pay $15

How do I code it so that I can validate if the user is in the database table of registered attendees and gets the $10 rate? (perhaps I can validate by email address used on the form)

This is what I have right now for my php file (It's defaulted on the $15 regular rate for non-attendees)

```
<html>
<div class="container">
    <head><title>Payment Page</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1>Step 2: Payment</h1>
    <p class="content">Please proceed onto payment via Paypal.</p>
<div></div>
<ul>
    <li>The fee for an attendee is $10</li>
    <li>The fee for a non-attendee is $15</li>

</ul>

    </body>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="container.css">
</head>

</html>

<div></div>
<br></br>


    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="tracyjones@gmail.com">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Fundraiser">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Rate">  
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">  
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">  
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">  
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">  
</form>
```

Comment: this more HTML than PHP. With HTML you should start with specifying your doctype before the HTML tag. B.T.W. this doctype differs from your other post. This is in HTML and your other form was in XHTML.

Comment: W.r.t. to my comment in our previous post place the style sheet link in inside the head tag. Important to not that there can only be one head in your HTML document.

Comment: All your HTML code should be wrapped in site the HTML tags. The content is placed inside the body tags. A typical structure would be <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>title<TITLE><link ... /></head><body>Content site</body></html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** 
Try this:

```
 <?php


// Event name
$event = "2013 VIA-1 5K Run Fundraiser";



// Registration fees for attendees and non-attendees
$fee_attendee = 10;
$fee_nonAttendee = 15;


$paypal_email = 'payment@example.com ';

// Registration closing date (will go until 11:59 PM Central Standard Time of this day)
$close_month = 03;
$close_day = 08;
$close_year = 2013;

// $time = time(); Easier to use the build in now function of MySQL. 


function clean($in)
{
    $out = trim(strip_tags($in));
    $out = addslashes($out);
    return $out;
}



function listform(){
$host = "host";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "dbname";

// open connection to databse
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //Get organisations from table organisations
           $query = "SELECT * FROM  organisations ORDER BY name ASC"; 
           $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
                    echo "<option value=".$row['id_organisations'].">".$row['name']."</option>\n";
                }
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
}

//Check if variables are post if so filter the input if not initiating variables for form
IF (isset($_POST['firstname'])){  
     $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    
}
ELSE {
    $firstname  = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['lastname'])){
            $lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
}
ELSE {
    $lastname   = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['org'])){
   $org = $_POST['org'];
}
ELSE {
    $org    = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
ELSE {
    $email  = "";
}

IF (isset($_POST['attendant'])){
    $attendant  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['attendant'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
ELSE {
    $attendant  = "";
}
IF (isset($_POST['waiver'])){
    $waiver = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['waiver'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
ELSE {
    $waiver  = "";
}



function submit_form(){
$host  = "host";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "dbname";

    $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $org    = $_POST['org'];
    $email  = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $attendant  = $_POST['attendant'];

    // open connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //INSERT VALUES INTO DATABASE
           $query = "INSERT INTO basicinfo (firstname,lastname,email,attendant,org,time) VALUES('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."', ".$attendant.", ".$org.", NOW())";
           return mysqli_query($link,$query);

        }
//close connection to database
        mysqli_close($link);

    }





function payment (){
$host = "host";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "dbname";

$firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$lastname   = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);





// open connection to databse
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //Is someone registered at other conference from table registration
           $query = "SELECT * FROM  registration WHERE firstname ='".$firstname."' AND lastname='".$lastname."'"; 
           $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
           $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);         
                if ( $rows > 0){
                    $amount = 10.00;
                    $form_registrar= <<< heredoc
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html>
<div class="container">
    <head><title>Payment Page</title></head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="container.css">
    <body>
    <h1>Step 2: Payment</h1>
    <p class="content">Please proceed onto payment via Paypal.</p>
<div></div>
<ul>
    <li>The fee for an attendee is $10</li>
    <li>The fee for a non-attendee is $15</li>

</ul>
<div>Your fee is $$amount</div>



    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="tracyjones@gmail.com">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Fundraiser">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Rate">  
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$amount">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">  
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">  
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">  
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">  
</form>

    </body>
</html>

heredoc;
                    return $form_registrar;
                }
                else {
                    $amount = 15.00;
                    $form_registrar= <<< heredoc
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html>
<div class="container">
    <head><title>Payment Page</title></head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="container.css">
    <body>
    <h1>Step 2: Payment</h1>
    <p class="content">Please proceed onto payment via Paypal.</p>
<div></div>
<ul>
    <li>The fee for an attendee is $10</li>
    <li>The fee for a non-attendee is $15</li>

</ul>
   <div>Your fee is $$amount</div>



    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="tracyjones@gmail.com">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Fundraiser">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Rate">  
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$amount">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">  
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">  
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">  
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">  
</form>

    </body>
</html>

heredoc;
                    return $form_registrar;
                }
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
}

//Warning messages initiation
$warning_firstname  = "*Required";
$warning_lastname   = "*Required";
$warning_org  = "*Required";
$warning_email   = "*Required";
$warning_attendant   = "*Required";
$warning_waiver      = "*Required";





$formfirstpart = <<<EODformfirspart
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form 5K RUN </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:gold">

            <div>We're excited to introduce the 5K Run to VIA-1! During this year's conference, Individuals can register to participate in the fun across University of Iowa's campus in order to raise money for this year's CPP</div>
    <div class="row">
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="registration">
           <div class="column grid_5">
               <label for='first'>First Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$firstname" /><span class="warning">$warning_firstname</span></br></br>
            <label for='first'>Last Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$lastname" /><span class="warning">$warning_lastname</span></br></br>
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='3' VALUE="$email" /><span class="warning">$warning_email</span></br></br>


           <label for="org">Organization:</label><br />
            <select id="org" name="org" tabindex="5">

EODformfirspart;

$formlastpart = <<<EODlastpart
                            </select>
                <span class="warning">$warning_org</span><br /><br />

                    <label for='attendant'>Are you attending VIA-1?</label><br />

                <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-yes' value='1' /> <label for='attendant-yes'>Yes</label><br />
            <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-no' value='0' /> <label for='attendant-no'>No </label><br />$warning_attendant<br />


            <input type='checkbox' class="radio" name="waiver" id="waiver" value="1"  /> <label for='waiver'>I understand and agree to the terms of <a href='waiver.php' target="_blank">the waiver</a>.$warning_waiver</label>
        </div>

    <div class='column grid_10 right'>
            <input type="submit" class='button' name="submit" value="submit" tabindex='7' />
            </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
EODlastpart;








IF(!IsSet($_POST['submit'])){ // Check if form is not send, if not display empty form.

echo $formfirstpart;
echo listform();
echo $formlastpart; 
}

ELSEIF (IsSet($_POST['submit']) AND (isset($firstname) OR isset($lastname) OR isset($email) OR  isset($org) OR isset($attendant))) {
$warning_counter = 0;
if ($firstname == "") {      
        $warning_firstname = 'Please provide your first name and / or a valid name';
                $warning_counter = + 1 ;
        }
if ($firstname == "") {      
        $warning_lastname = 'Please provide your last name and / or a valid name';
                $warning_counter = + 1;
        }
if ($email == "") {      
        $warning_email = 'Please provide your email adress and / or a valid email adress';
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }

if ($org == " ") {      
        $warning_org = 'Please select your organisation';
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }

if ($waiver == "") {      
        $warning_waiver = 'You have to accept the waiver agreement the otherwise you cannot attend'; 
                $warning_counter = +1;
        }
if ($attendant == "") {      
        $warning_attendant = 'Do you attend VIA-1?';
                $warning_counter =+1;
        } 
 if ($warning_counter>0){               
$formfirstpart1 = <<<EODformfirspart1
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form 5K RUN </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:gold">

            <div>We're excited to introduce the 5K Run to VIA-1! During this year's conference, Individuals can register to participate in the fun across University of Iowa's campus in order to raise money for this year's CPP</div>
    <div class="row">
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="registration">
           <div class="column grid_5">
               <label for='first'>First Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$firstname" /><span class="warning">$warning_firstname</span></br></br>
            <label for='first'>Last Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="$lastname" /><span class="warning">$warning_lastname</span></br></br>
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='3' VALUE="$email" /><span class="warning">$warning_email</span></br></br>


           <label for="org">Organization:</label><br />
            <select id="org" name="org" tabindex="5">


EODformfirspart1;



$formlastpart1 = <<<EODlastpart1

                            </select>
                <span class="warning">$warning_org</span><br /><br />

                    <label for='attendant'>Are you attending VIA-1?</label><br />

                <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-yes' value='1' /> <label for='attendant-yes'>Yes</label><br />
            <input type='radio' class='radio' name='attendant' id='attendant-no' value='0' /> <label for='attendant-no'>No </label><br />$warning_attendant<br />


            <input type='checkbox' class="radio" name="waiver" id="waiver" value="1"  /> <label for='waiver'>I understand and agree to the terms of <a href='waiver.php' target="_blank">the waiver</a>.$warning_waiver</label>
        </div>

    <div class='column grid_10 right'>
            <input type="submit" class='button' name="submit" value="submit" tabindex='7' />
            </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>

EODlastpart1;
    echo $formfirstpart1;
    echo listform();
    echo $formlastpart1;
 }
 IF ($warning_counter == 0){
submit_form();
echo payment();

 }
}


?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried and the pages render and all, but the Paypal prices aren't working. The price is $10 regardless of whether the user is in the registration table or not.

Comment: Could it be it's not querying from the registered attendees table correctly?

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by an attendee is $10 and an non attendee is $15. With the registration table I am referring to the table with the users that have already registered for another conference. BTW you may want to remove the email adress.

Comment: I think that you are correct. the table with the users that have registered for another conference get the fee of $10 and the ones that have not registered have the rate of $15. sorry for the confusion!

Comment: In your post it says that you get a $10 discount, but if think you mean a $5 discount.

Comment: Whoops. I apologize about not being transparent in my post. I meant a payment of $10 ($5 discount) intead of a $10 discount. you are correct

Comment: The script works fine in terms of not generating any error messages and the pages looks as it should. The only function not working is applying the correct fees.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, for the email I used, it's not the real one I'm going to use due to security reasons, so that won't be an issue. Thanks for checking :)

Comment: I have adjusted the if statement and I think it will work now. See my edit above.

Comment: I got this error after submitting the form and getting to the payment page "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in line 153" The Paypal "buy now" button appears but the fee is automatically set to $15 regardless of whether the user is registered for the other conference or not. It seems there's an error with "$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH); "

Comment: Could you post the structure of the table with the already registered users in sql fiddle?

Comment: could the issue be that in this structure, i have "first" and "last" instead of "firstname" and "lastname"?

Comment: yes, that could be the problem. Change ` $query = "SELECT * FROM  registration WHERE firstname ='".$firstname."' AND lastname='".$lastname."'";` into ` $query = "SELECT * FROM  registration WHERE first ='".$firstname."' AND last='".$lastname."'";`

Comment: I just tried that and IT WORKS!! Thank you so much!! I "accepted" your answer!

Comment: You are getting better at this debugging stuff.

Comment: Ha, I'm working on it. Wow you really have alleviated a lot of stress from me. I have a learned a lot from you, so much appreciated for your timely responses and willingness to help me!

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do here is change the price, so around the

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
```

Next you query for the list of names:

```
<?php
require_once{'config.php');

$query="SELECT * FROM usertable";
$result=mysql_query($query) or exit("Sql Error".mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result)-1; 

$in=0;
for ($i=0; $i<=$num_results;$i++){
$userindb=mysql_result($result,$i,"usernamecolumn");
if ($userindb==$userinputted){
echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='10.00'>";
$in=1;
exit;
}
}
if ($in==0){
echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='15.00'>";}

?>
```

Of course you will have to retrieve the post data and set it to $userinputted.
I hope this helped, ask me more about details if required.

Comment: It would be better if the SQL itself looks up for user by `where` clause in it. Ofcourse, it must be validated first to prevent SQL injection.